# YUI DataTable .NET webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, yui-datatable

Does anyone have an example of using of populating a YUI DataTable with a .NET webservice?

Thanks in advance. 
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this a while back: 
http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/09/dynamic_data_experimenting_wit.html

However, you will need control over the webservice so that you can turn it into XML, or JSON or whatever format you wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

DataTable Control: XML Data Over XHR (Ajax Request) With POST

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_xhrpostxml.html

Answer (score 0):

Working with the YUI DataTable, Part 1: Getting Started

http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/10/15/datatable-260-part-one